# Underbrace in matrix problem

Tags: matrices

I have the latex code below for a matrix which I want to define. The problem is that in the 5th column the terms overlap with the 4th column and the right "edge" of the matrix. Can this be solved easily?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{undertilde}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{dsfont} % For using Indicator function
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[sort&compress,round,comma,authoryear]{natbib}%bibtex
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}% for appendix met A
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{enumitem} % For labeling enumeration
\newcommand{\sunderb}[2]{
  \mathclap{\underbrace{\makebox[#1]{0 $\cdots$ 0}}_{#2}}
}

\begin{document}

$$V=
  \begin{pmatrix}
  B_{21}(0)& B_{22}(0)  & B_{23}(0)& 0 & \sunderb{3.5em}{12} \\
  \sunderb{3.5em}{4}  & B_{21}(0)& B_{22}(0) & B_{23}(0) & \sunderb{3.5em}{9} \\ 
  \sunderb{3.5em}{8}  & B_{21}(0)& B_{22}(0) & B_{23}(0) & \sunderb{3.5em}{5} \\
  \sunderb{3.5em}{12} & B_{21}(0)& B_{22}(0) & B_{23}(0) & 0 
  \end{pmatrix}
}\in \R^{4 \times 16}.$$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After guessing at a definition for `\R` and removing a stray brace, I modified the `\sunderb` macro by adding an outer `\makebox[#1]`.  Without it, you ar relying on the natural width of other items in the column to compensate for the `\mathclap`.  When a column, like the last one of the matrix, has nothing else that wide, it provokes the overlap.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{undertilde}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{dsfont} % For using Indicator function
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[sort&compress,round,comma,authoryear]{natbib}%bibtex
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}% for appendix met A
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{enumitem} % For labeling enumeration
\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\sunderb}[2]{\makebox[#1]{$\mathclap{\underbrace{\makebox[#1]{0 $\cdots$ 0}}_{#2}}$}%
}

\begin{document}

\[V=
  \begin{pmatrix}
  B_{21}(0)& B_{22}(0)  & B_{23}(0)& 0 & \sunderb{3.5em}{12} \\
  \sunderb{3.5em}{4}  & B_{21}(0)& B_{22}(0) & B_{23}(0) & \sunderb{3.5em}{9} \\ 
  \sunderb{3.5em}{8}  & B_{21}(0)& B_{22}(0) & B_{23}(0) & \sunderb{3.5em}{5} \\
  \sunderb{3.5em}{12} & B_{21}(0)& B_{22}(0) & B_{23}(0) & 0 
  \end{pmatrix}
\in \R^{4 \times 16}.\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need a `\mathclap` in the definition of `\sunderb`. Also, I reduced slighlty the value of the width (1st argument) as it looks better for my taste. A final comment: needless to load `amstext`: `mathtools` does it for you. Same comment for `graphics`, loaded by `graphicx`, and finally, `epsfig` is deprecated in favour of `graphicx`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\sunderb}[2]{\underbrace{\makebox[#1]{$0 ⋯ 0$}}_{#2}}


\begin{document}

$$V=
\begin{pmatrix}
  B_{21}(0) & B_{22}(0) & B_{23}(0) & 0 & \sunderb{3em}{12} \\
  \sunderb{3em}{4} & B_{21}(0) & B_{22}(0) & B_{23}(0) & \sunderb{3em}{9} \\
  \sunderb{3em}{8} & B_{21}(0) & B_{22}(0) & B_{23}(0) & \sunderb{3em}{5} \\
  \sunderb{3em}{12} & B_{21}(0) & B_{22}(0) & B_{23}(0) & 0
\end{pmatrix}
 ∈ \mathbb R^{4 × 16}.$$

\end{document}
```

[image]